¿Quiero guardar esta imagen y al momento de guardar información en el formulario?

Tiene que grabarlo en un path, pero el problema era que cuando llenaba los datos y faltaba algún dato y daba grabar, se perdía la imagen.
private void SaveImages(MedicalDateViewModel medicalDate)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(medicalDate.FirmaBase64))
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(medicalDate.RutaFirma(), Convert.FromBase64String(medicalDate.FirmaBase64));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(medicalDate.FotoBase64))
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(medicalDate.RutaFoto(), Convert.FromBase64String(medicalDate.FotoBase64));
    }

}
public Customer GetCustomerByIdentifier(string identifier)
{
    return _customerRepository.GetFromExternalApiByIdentifier(identifier);
}

public ExamDocument SaveLaboratoryResults(MedicalExam medicalExam, bool reload = false)
{
    return _externalExamsRepository.SaveLaboratoryResults(medicalExam, reload);
}

public ServiceResult MarkMedicalDateAsConfirmed(int id)
{
    var model = _repository.FindById(id);
    if (model.HasStarted) return ServiceResult.UnsuccessResult("Esta cita ya ha sido marcada como realizada");

    model.ExamStateId = (int)MedicalExamStates.InProgress;
    model.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
    _repository.Edit(model);
    return ServiceResult.SuccessResult();
}


Bienvenido. Ten cuidado dónde escribes. Parece que quisiste cargar una imagen pero te cargaste el link. Por cierto, puedes ser más claro?

tiene que grabarlo en una path
peor el problema era que cuando llenaba los datos y faltaba algun dato y daba grabar
se perdia la imagen

A ver si entiendo: Tienes un formulario donde cargas varios datos y al menos uno de ellos es una imagen. Enviar el formulario al guardar, pero en el caso que la validación desde el servidor falla, devuelves la página con los datos precargados (para que el usuario corrija) pero la imagen no se devuelve y se pierde. Es así??' o es otra cosa?

Cómo que el problema era? A caso ya no tienes ese problema? Si es así, cuál es ahora? Espero que otro sí te pueda entender

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

@Yussef Hola asi es como tu lo dices!

@como  lo puedo solucionar!
